# Fullcalendar event constraint

Tags: jquery, angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I am trying to constraint event drag and drop with FullCalendar using businessHours and eventConstraint. Unfortunately sometimes I have exceptionnal schedules that I represent with backgroundEvent and I set the "option overlap: true" to allow drag and drop on this event (because they are not in businessHours). But with the constraint eventConstraint="businessHours" the drag and drop don't work when the exceptionnal schedules is not in businessHours. How can allow the drag and drop on businnesHours and exceptionnal schedules?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you provide some code ? To show what you tried, this way it's easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow !

```
 /* This constrains it to today or later */
    eventConstraint: {
      start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      end: '2100-01-01', // hard coded goodness unfortunately
      dow: [1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5]
    },
```

Comment: Not Working when we use both

Comment: Do you happen to know how to use eventConstraint in the angular version of fullcalendar?